# Problema ao usar parâmetro em um PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, prepared-statement

Gostaria de saber se há algum problema em usar a variável "parametro" após o "AND", pois quando testei colocando o nome da coluna diretamente na SQL funcionou e quando tento passar o nome da coluna com o parâmetro não retorna nada. Há o que eu possa fazer para que isso dê certo?
**OBS:** O nome da coluna não será passado em um jTextField, será escolhido por meio de jRadioButtons.

```
public List<Evento> buscar(String parametro,String pesq){
    PreparedStatement stmt  = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Evento> busca = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id_evento,nome_cliente,numero,cidade,dia,horario,equipamento,pagamento " +
                                    "FROM cliente c INNER JOIN evento e ON (e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente) AND ? LIKE ?");
        stmt.setString(1, parametro);
        stmt.setString(2, "%"+pesq+"%");

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            Evento evento = new Evento();

            evento.setId_evento(rs.getInt("id_evento"));
            evento.setNome(rs.getNString("nome_cliente"));
            evento.setNumero(rs.getNString("numero"));
            evento.setCidade(rs.getNString("cidade"));
            evento.setData(rs.getNString("dia"));
            evento.setHorario(rs.getNString("horario"));
            evento.setEquipamento(rs.getNString("equipamento"));
            evento.setPagamento(rs.getNString("pagamento"));

            busca.add(evento);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        ConexaoBD.closeConnection(con, (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) stmt, rs);
    }
    return busca;
}
```

Tentei da seguinte forma, como @Sorack e @CarlosHeuberger me recomendaram:

```
public List<Evento> buscar(int parametro,String nome,String numero){
    PreparedStatement stmt  = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Evento> busca = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT id_evento,\n" +
                                    "      nome_cliente,\n" +
                                    "      numero,\n" +
                                    "      cidade,\n" +
                                    "      dia,\n" +
                                    "      horario,\n" +
                                    "      equipamento,\n" +
                                    "      pagamento\n" +
                                    "FROM cliente c INNER JOIN evento e ON e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente\n" +
                                    "WHERE CASE ?\n" +
                                    "      1 THEN nome_cliente LIKE ?\n" +
                                    "      2 THEN cidade LIKE ?\n" +
                                    "      END");
        stmt.setInt(1, parametro);
        stmt.setString(2, "%"+nome+"%");
        stmt.setString(3, "%"+numero+"%");

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){

            Evento evento = new Evento();

            evento.setId_evento(rs.getInt("id_evento"));
            evento.setNome(rs.getNString("nome_cliente"));
            evento.setNumero(rs.getNString("numero"));
            evento.setCidade(rs.getNString("cidade"));
            evento.setData(rs.getNString("dia"));
            evento.setHorario(rs.getNString("horario"));
            evento.setEquipamento(rs.getNString("equipamento"));
            evento.setPagamento(rs.getNString("pagamento"));

            busca.add(evento);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EventoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        ConexaoBD.closeConnection(con, (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) stmt, rs);
    }
    return busca;
}
```

Mas deu esse erro:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 THEN nome_cliente LIKE '%João%' 2 THEN cidade LIKE '%João%'
```

O que pode ser dessa vez?

OBS: Os valores dos LIKE's são os mesmos, porque eu tô usando um mesmo TextField para pegar os valores.

Comment: Desculpa, @CarlosHeuberger, eu percebi agora que coloquei "nome da tabela", mas na verdade é o nome da coluna que eu quero passar como parâmetro. Irei fazer a correção.

Comment: O nome da coluna também não pode ser enviado como parâmetro. Para fazer o que você quer você precisa montar a  `query`em tempo de execução

Comment: Obrigado, @Sorack, mas pode me explicar melhor isso que disse? Desculpa, não entendi bem.

Comment: Valeu pelas dicas, @CarlosHeuberger!

Comment: @Jov1c o problema ocorre porque passando a variável por parâmetro ele transforma em `srtring` ai sua `query` ficaria mais ou menos assim: `WHERE 'campo' = 'valor'`.

Comment: Porém, essas aspas que contornam o campo não poderiam existir.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger acho que a sugestão do `CASE-WHEN` é melhor que montar a `query` em tempo de execução. Passa a coluna me parece uma decisão de arquitetura meio ruim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não consegue passar o nome da coluna para um `PreparedStatement`. Uma solução para contornar o seu problema é verificar qual coluna foi selecionada no `WHERE` da `query`:

```
SELECT id_evento,
      nome_cliente,
      numero,
      cidade,
      dia,
      horario,
      equipamento,
      pagamento
  FROM cliente c INNER JOIN evento e ON e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente
 WHERE (? = 1 AND nome_cliente LIKE ?)
    OR (? = 2 AND cidade LIKE ?)
```

Na `query` acima, caso o primeiro parâmetro tenha o valor `1` a coluna utilizada na busca será a `nome_cliente`, caso seja `2` será a `cidade`. Você pode implementar quais colunas quiser apenas adicionando mais um `OR` na condição.

Ou você pode utilizar um `CASE` como o colega @CarlosHeuberger citou:

```
SELECT id_evento,
      nome_cliente,
      numero,
      cidade,
      dia,
      horario,
      equipamento,
      pagamento
  FROM cliente c INNER JOIN evento e ON e.fk_cliente = c.id_cliente
WHERE CASE ?
        1 THEN nome_cliente LIKE ?
        2 THEN cidade LIKE ?
      END
```